# How to have a textfield load with todays date through NSDate?

Tags: ios, nsdate

How do I have a textfield with on viewdidLoad load with today's date? i think it requires nsdateformatter but i don't know how to do it if somebody could provide some code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"];
NSDate *todaysDate = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"Todays date is %@",[formatter stringFromDate:todaysDate]);
```